# Rigid body not falling down; flies away in a different direction

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'm new to Blender (2.92) and was following this [conveyor belt animation tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDwxGPsfG6E&ab_channel=MajesticSkies) . I decided to use a heart-shaped model as the object that would move along the conveyor belt. When I added the rigid body physics property and pressed play, the heart would "fly" away to a completely different direction *or* would rotate profusely and would eventually fall down into nowhere. Basically, when I press play, the heart does everything but go down, land on the conveyor belt, and move along with it.

I tested the rigid body physics property on a regular cube and it worked—meaning that the cube would land on the conveyor belt and move along with it. But for some reason, I always have a problem when it comes to the heart model. Is the issue I'm having caused by the heart model? Or could it have to do with my conveyor belt?

My aim for this animation is to make the heart lay flat and move along with the conveyor belt (as seen in the YouTube tutorial I followed). I would really appreciate any help/guidance I can get!

This is what the heart looks like before I press the play button (I rotated it so that it lays flat and it's also slightly above my conveyor belt):
[image]

This is what the heart looks like when I press the play button (it rotates and "flies" away in a completely different direction):
[image]

These are the rigid body settings I have set for my conveyor belt:
[image]

And these are the rigid body settings I have set for the heart:
[image]

Comment: did you apply scale & rotation? if that doen't help, please provide blend file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my fix was deleting bake in scene properties and rebaking.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and procedure. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the workflow and how it works, feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be converted to a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Since the question states that he also tried a cube and it worked, then switched back to the heart model it's unlikely that it's the bake, since it would have been deleted / overwritten when simulating the cube.